# Can I use the Microsoft Exchange 2013 API from Java?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Can I work with the EWS of Exchange 2013 from Java? I found that the 2013 version of EWS doesn't is supported by the Java EWS API.

Comment: I still feel this part of the question "I found that the 2013 version of EWS doesn't is supported by the Java EWS API." is unanswered. I dont think 2013 version support is not yet available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EWS API is a SOAP-based API, and therefore yes, you can use it from Java or any other language that lets you POST XML data over HTTP. The commercial JWebServices component mentioned in another answer is a  library that wraps the SOAP calls for you into helper functions.

Microsoft's [EWS Java library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) does appear to be updated infrequently, but it's free, so you get what you pay for I suppose.

Comment: Download moved to http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-EWS-Java-API-12-1a5a1143

Comment: Project moved to github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api. Stable version is not available only snapshots are there

Answer (score 1):

There is another API called [JWebServices for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.com/jwebservices).

Supports all new features in Exchange 2013

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. ews-java-api is now open source and deployed to sonatype [nexus](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;gav~com.microsoft.ews-java-api~ews-java-api~2.0~~)