# How to create item in a shared calendar use java

Tags: calendar, exchange-server

Seems EWS(Exchange Web Service) don't have this feature, does anyone know how to access or create an item in a shared calendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612829/can-i-use-the-microsoft-exchange-2013-api-from-java/21634513

Answer (score 0):

EWS does allow for delegate access. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn641956(v=exchg.150).aspx.

Comment: I can access the default calendar folder and it's item, but don't know how to access the shared calendar, any idea?